# only inline style working with css

Tags: html, css

I have some code that is a simple div with a css stylesheet that has:

```
#upgrade-message {
   margin: 15px 0px;
   padding: 15px 10px 15px 50px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: 10px center; 
   color: #00529B; 
   background-color: #BDE5F8;
   background-image: url('../../../../templates/yoo_vanilla/images/typography/box_info.png');
   display: block;
   clear: left;
   float: right;
}

#upgrade-message a:link {
   color: black;
}
```

The code is (in php but you get the idea):

```
echo "<div id=\"upgrade-message\">A message: <a href=\"ppay\">Upgrade</a> now!</div>";
```

The a:link part of my css is not getting applied. Basically I just want to change the "Upgrade" text to black. If I put an inline style it works great.

I can't see any conflict on my site as I check it with Firebug and the other parts of the css with `upgrade-message` are applying. I also see the css in firebug but it doesn't seem to apply. I've even tried this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DDp5r/) to make sure it was the right syntax.

Can anyone shed any light on why the css with `a:link` is not applying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you have already visit the link? And so the CSS isn't applied. Use

```
#upgrade-message a { }
```

or for modern browser or with more compatibility:

```
#upgrade-message a:link,
#upgrade-message a:hover,
#upgrade-message a:visited,
#upgrade-message a:active {
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Of course, be aware that some styling is disabled on `:visited` for security purposes.

Comment: oh brother, that was dumb on my part. Thanks!